# Spring MVC static resources 404 - for old Spring 1.2x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is one of the common question for Spring and the below answer solves the problem.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
```

But my problem is different, in old Spring 1.2x, we don't have this tag. We have to manually handle. Please help me how to handle this issue in older Spring 1.2x. Maybe some configuration with `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` or in web.xml?

Comment: You didn't mention explicitly, so I'll ask: did you consider upgrading to a modern version of Spring instead? Yours is 9-11 years old and an upgrade could be a better use of your time (and guaranteed to bring other benefits and give access to all the new functionality introduced over the years)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest mapping the dispatcher servlet in the web.xml to something other than "/". That way, requests for static resources won't be processed by Spring.

For example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/actions/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That being said, I highly suggest upgrading to a recent version of Spring.